# VS Code not running queries

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code

I have a take home project, I have to connect to a Postgres SQL, run some queries, make changes to a repo and push my changes. I have successfully connected to the database (I'm able to see everything when I select the elephant and I have it selected at the bottom of my screen). When I write a simple code and execute, I get both message "Query Completed in 4.2 sec." and "Waiting for query to complete"

After a while, I get an error message that the window is not responding, you can reopen the window or keep waiting". Everything should be up to date (I downloaded the latest software as of Sept 1st 2022). What step am I missing? I was expecting the results of my query.

Please let me know what to check

[image]

Comment: Is the data large? I wonder if the client is waiting for data to come through the pipe. If the table is large, that could take some time. I'm not sure how VSCode handles that.

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to be saved (Ctrl + S for Windows) before the query can be executed.